# Working with changing namespace prefixes

Tags: c#, sql-server, xpath, xquery, xml-namespaces

Let's say I get two different xml documents from two different vendors using the same schema.  They each chose different namespace prefixes.  How can I query for the value of "Foo" and "Bar" in a generic fashion using XPATH in both C# and SQL Server?  For brevity, The XML looks roughly like this:

Document 1

```
<a:Item xmlns:a="http://kakridge.com/schema">Foo</a:Item>
```

Document 2

```
<b:Item xmlns:b="http://kakridge.com/schema">Bar</a:Item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath doesn't care what prefixes appear in the source documents, it only cares about the namespace URI. If the prefix z is bound to the namespace http://kakridge.com/schema, then //z:Item will find the Item elements in both these documents.

Comment: Understood, but if one document is //z:Item and another document is //y:Item, how do you rectify that generically?  This may be an implementation detail, but I'm thinking I ignore the prefix and define my own.  As you said, as long as the URI matches, I wouldn't expect it to be a problem.  It would take some research though.  Christian's suggestion actually works in SQL Server.  By the way, I loved your XSLT book years ago.

Comment: @kakridge: The prefixes don't matter -- they may be different. As long as they are bound to the same namespace. you can use a *third* prefix, fifferent form these two (say `"t"`) and use `t:Item` in the XPath expression. I know that you probably don't believe this -- just try it.

Comment: I believe it.  I think I am mostly encountering deficiencies in the tools I am limited to currently.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for the value of `Item`, which is `Foo` and `bar`? If the local name of your element will be the same, a wildcard should help you:

```
//*:Item/text()
```

Comment: He's in the Microsoft world, Christian, so I imagine his XPath engine doesn't support XPath 2.0 syntax.